# Strange UITableView behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I am experiencing a strange bug in my UITableView. I have two cells, `SummaryHeaderTableViewCell` and `MapTableViewCell`. They are 400 and 200 pixels tall. I have two rows, and first row should be the summary cell, and the second should be map cell.

But still, the views in the simulator shows like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell

    if indexPath == 0 {

        let summaryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SummaryHeaderTableViewCell

        summaryCell.nameLabel.text = detailItem!["navn"] as? String
        summaryCell.addressLabel.text = "\(detailItem!["adrlinje1"]), \(detailItem!["adrlinje2"])"
        summaryCell.cityLabel.text = detailItem!["poststed"] as? String

        let inspectionDate: String = detailItem!["dato"] as! String
        summaryCell.inspectionDateLabel.text = self.convertDateString(inspectionDate)

        cell = summaryCell
    }
    else
    {
        let mapCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MapTableViewCell

        // Set map options

        cell = mapCell
    }

    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 400.0
    } else {
        return 200.0
    }
}
```

Here is the storyboard with dynamic prototypes:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to row instead of section in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 400.0
    } else {
        return 200.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only having a single `section` in the `UITableView` and the different items are populated on two different rows, not sections.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let summaryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SummaryHeaderTableViewCell
        summaryCell.nameLabel.text = detailItem!["navn"] as? String
        summaryCell.addressLabel.text = "\(detailItem!["adrlinje1"]), \(detailItem!["adrlinje2"])"
        summaryCell.cityLabel.text = detailItem!["poststed"] as? String
        let inspectionDate: String = detailItem!["dato"] as! String
        summaryCell.inspectionDateLabel.text = self.convertDateString(inspectionDate)
        return summaryCell
    }
    else
    {
        let mapCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MapTableViewCell
        // Set map options
        return mapCell
    }
}
```

Also

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
         return 400.0
    }
    else {
         return 200.0
    }
}
```